# Pandas: Super categories the category data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm following the [Kaggle's Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)  dataset problem. I have a dataframe which contains many columns. One of them is a column called `Cabin`(Categorical data) which contains Cabin number assigned to the passenger, 
 and another column `Survived` containing only `0` and `1` ( 0-not survived and 1-survived)

```
Survived   Parch            Ticket        Fare      Cabin   Embarked  
0          0            A/5 21171       7.2500       C85        S  
1          0             PC 17599      71.2833       C85        C  
1          0              3101282       7.9250       C85        S  
0          0               113803      53.1000      A123        S  
0          0               373450       8.0500      B123        S
```

I want to group these data on the basis of the Cabin and see how many people survived from each group/Cabin. I tried using groupby function

```
df.groupby(["Cabin"]["Survived"].sum()
```

This divides the data into too much detailed groups.

```
A10      0
A14      2
A16      1
A19      4
A20      5
F38      1
F4       3
G6       7
T        0
```

Instead, i want them to be grouped on the basis of Cabin A , Cabin B, Cabin C and so on.

```
A   30
B   0
C   40
```

I thought of using a dictionary to store all different A's, B's etc.

```
dic = {"A": ["A10", "A34", "A36", "A5", "A6", "A7"],
       "B": ["B101", "B102", "B18", "B19", "B20"],
        .....................
      }
```

But since there are 147 different categories (A2, A3, B56, F45......), it is too much to do just for a single task. Is there any inbuild function that can help in achieving this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `groupby` the first letter.

```
df

   Survived  Parch     Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked
0         0      0  A/5 21171   7.2500   C85        S
1         1      0   PC 17599  71.2833   C85        C
2         1      0    3101282   7.9250   C85        S
3         0      0     113803  53.1000  A123        S
4         0      0     373450   8.0500  B123        S

df.groupby(df.Cabin.str[0]).Survived.sum()

Cabin
A    0
B    0
C    2
Name: Survived, dtype: int64
```

You don't have to go through the trouble of creating a dictionary.

Comment: Surprisingly I answered same here yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129267/how-to-groupby-pandas-dataframe-by-customized-function/46996369#46996369 No one saw that

Comment: @Bharath Hmm... if it is a dupe, maybe it should be marked (I can't do that since I already answered the Q).

Comment: @Bharath Oh! Didn't see the link. :-)

Comment: i still think COLDSPEED's approach is better than the one answered that linked post. ayways this hass  solved my problem.

Comment: You know the linked one had only numbers so no astype(str) required here. Or else coldspeed would have done the same.

Comment: I meant by the accepted one.I understood why you did astype there.The accepted answer of that post does seems to be lengthier